# Decision for Ubuntu or Lubuntu on little bit Old notebook

Tags: dual-boot, lubuntu, system-requirements

Currently i have an Acer Aspire 2930 with 3 GB RAM,and according to the net,Lubuntu is the lightest Ubuntu derivative.

Can you guys tell me technically (But not to technical) how could Lubuntu become lighter than normal Ubuntu ? What are advantages and disadvantages of each OS ?

Should i choose Lubuntu or Ubuntu to be Dual-booted with Windows 7 on my Aspire ?

Sorry for this such question,i'm just new to Ubuntu

Comment: How fast is your processor?

Comment: Dual core 2 GHZ,with 2 MB L2 Cache (Intel Core T6400)

Comment: I think it isn't duplicate,since i'm asking about comparison between Lubuntu and Ubuntu and which is best,but thankyou anyway for the other refrence :)

Comment: If you really read the reference, find the answer you will.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Lubuntu uses LXDE for the Desktop Manager (the GUI), which supposedly runs with only 512 MB of RAM as opposed to Unity, which is a known memory hog. Thus, it would be "lighter". From the LXDE site:

> **Lightweight**
>
> It needs less CPU and performs extremely well with reasonable memory.
>
> **Fast**
>
> It runs well even on older computers produced in 1999, and it does not require 3D acceleration.

...

> The hardware requirements of LXDE are similiar to Windows 98 (Maybe a little bit higher). An old Pentium II CPU is enough.
>
> After X11 and LXDE are started, the total memory usage is about 45 MB on i386 machines. (This value may be higher or lower according to
> different system configurations.)
>
> Though LXDE itself doesn't require better hardware, other applications under X do need it. For example, Firefox and
> OpenOffice.org 2 are quite memory-hungry. So it's recommended that you
> have a RAM of more than 128 MB.

As for the applications that come default installed with Lubuntu, they are lighter and run on less RAM. They may have less features, but they are built to run on older equipment, such as my iBook G4 (downloading the iso for Lubuntu 12.04 now :D).

You can read here: https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Lubuntu#Lubuntu_vs_Ubuntu about the comparison. Basically, what makes Lubuntu lighter (faster) is the DE, LXDE.

Thus, LXDE itself runs lighter/better on older/limited hardware. You can read more about this on the LXDE about site: http://lxde.org/lxde.

As for which one to go with, I would try going with Lubuntu first and then if you want it, install Unity. I've heard (not confirmed though) that Lubuntu is faster overall and thus you can just add the apps you want after the install.

I have an old 7-8 yr old Toshiba Satellite A105 with 1GB of RAM and Unity runs, for the most part, great on that. If I have a large number of tabs open in Firefox or several apps running at once it slows down, but usually its fine!

So, it really comes down to the speed-features trade-off. Unity/Ubuntu seems to have more features, but LXDE/Lubuntu has more speed. It's really your choice.

Comment: So then,what is disadvantage of Lubuntu ?

Comment: I can't really think of anything major regarding the software, as you can always install apps that don't come with Lubuntu. The only thing I can think of is that Lubuntu doesn't have an LTS version, it only comes with the 18 month support version, as per here: https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Lubuntu#Lubuntu_vs_Ubuntu. As I mentioned in my answer, quoted from the page: `Lubuntu 12.04 is not an LTS (5 years support), but a standard release that is supported for 18 months (if you would like to change this please feel free to contact the developers to offer assistance in this area).`